# Maclaurin Series for $\operatorname{erf}(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, uniform-convergence, error-function

I am attempting to compose the Maclaurin series for $\operatorname{erf}(z)$.

My disclaimer is that I am not an expert in the field of complex analysis. Below is my attempt. I am worried about convergence assumptions and / the integration term by term technique. I wonder if I am in the right direction on this?

*Problem*
To determine the Maclaurin series for $\operatorname{erf}(z)$.

We have, by definition
$$\operatorname{erf}(z) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\displaystyle \int_0^z e^{-t^2}dt$$

Since
$$e^{-z^2} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(\frac{(-z^2)^j}{j!}\right),\qquad |z|<\infty $$
and (here is my worry) *the convergence is uniform on the closure* of $\bar{B}(\pi i , r)$ for **any** $r \in (0, \infty)$, I can then describe term by integration as
$$\operatorname{erf}(z) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^j z^{2j+1})}{j!(2j+1)}\right),\qquad |z|<\infty$$

Any pointers here if I have made mistakes would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have a typo in the result.  $\frac{2}{\sqrt{z}}$ should be $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$.  Otherwise, it looks right to me.

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you for spotting that, made the answer useless!

Comment: A power series is always uniformly convergent on any compact set inside of the circle of convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct.

Both $z \mapsto e^{-z^2}$ and $z \mapsto \text{erf }  (z)$ are entire functions and can be expanded in convergent power series for  any $z$.

We have a general theorem that a power series can be integrated termwise along any path within the circle of convergence, which in this case has an infinite radius.